# Windows 7 : Sorting contents of a file

Tags: windows-7

Is there any functionality by which I can sort the contents of a file in place in windows 7 ?

I am not sure if there is any way I could do it in UI, but is there any batch script which will help me do it ?

An example of what I am trying to do.

Let file "data.txt" containing the follwing data be the input file

```
A12
A04
B08
B01
```

The output data.txt should contain

```
A04
A12
B01
B08
```

Basically, something like a natural sort.

How can I achieve this in windows 7

Comment: What do you mean by sort a file? Sort the contents? By what order? Or do you mean to sort the file list? How do you want to do it, programatically, or through the Windows UI?

Comment: Made the question more clear.

Comment: @cmv: You actually didn't make it any more clear.  Ray's questions still stand.  What exactly are you trying to do?  What kind of file are you talking about?  Sort it how?

Comment: I edited the question once more.

Answer (score 15):

windows 7 and much older versions of windows have an exe:  **sort.exe** it makes exactly what you want (as I understud your question) use it as:

```
sort <data.txt >newData.txt
```

Comment: but `sort` command doesn't seem to support *natural* sort

Comment: result is completely wrong and not sorted (on WIn10 at least)

Answer (score 4):

Start a command prompt window.

Type `help sort` in order to see and then enter the syntax right.

You will find that the command is `sort data.txt /o newData.txt`.

Check your work by entering `type data.txt` to display the original data, and then `type newData.txt` to see the sorted file contents.

Comment: the final command should have been **type newData.txt** I missed bolding the first word.